# How can I get HAPROXY to recognise that a server is up when a servlet is listening on a root context?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to setup haproxy so that http requests are routed to servlets hosted by websphere.

The servlets have a root context set so that:

```
wget  [host]:[port]/[root context]
```

returns a response were as

```
wget  [host]:[port]
```

returns 404

How can I configure haproxy so that a proxy defined something like this:

```
listen MyProxy aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:80 
mode http 
...      
server SERVER1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080 cookie SERVER_01 check 
...
```

doesn't result in haproxy reporting the server is down with a 404? I can't see where I can specify a root context.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the URL to check using "option httpchk". For instance :

```
 option httpchk /index.html
```